# Unrecognized element 'authentication'.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to write a simple authentication. I'm also trying to make this quick and learn about the forms authentication via web.config.

So i have my authentication working if I hard code my 'user name' and 'password' into C# code and do a simple conditional.

However, I get en error message '**Unrecognized element 'authentication'.**

```
Line 2:     <system.web>
Line 3:         <customErrors mode="off">
Line 4:             <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 5:                 <forms name=".C#FEWD" 
Line 6:                     loginUrl="/schools/admin/login/index.aspx"
```

My web.config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="off">
            <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms name=".C#FEWD" 
                    loginUrl="/schools/admin/login/index.aspx" 
                    protection="All" 
                    timeout="60">
                    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                        <user name="schools" password="magic" />
                    </credentials>
                </forms>
            </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its probably just that you're missing the node terminator from your customErrors setting:

```
<customErrors mode="off"/>
```

More following comment:

Your complete config should be:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="off" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".C#FEWD" 
                loginUrl="/schools/admin/login/index.aspx" 
                protection="All" 
                timeout="60">
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="schools" password="magic" />
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There is node terminator for customError setting.

Comment: Ah - `<authentication>` shouldn't be a child of the `<customError>` setting  - terminate `<customError>` and put `<authentication>` afterwards (see edit)

Comment: No problem. Feel free to click on the "tick" next to my answer to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, the `<authorization>` node should not be a child of the `<customErrors>` node.